How do I change color of line connecting opening and closing brace in Intellij?
When I read through large code chunks, its hard to keep track of where I am in the method, especially if the method is really big. Is there a way to change the color of the opening/closing bracket line connector to make it more obvious and easy to follow?
Intellij opening/closing brase line indicator 

You can use plugins like Rainbow Brackets if you just want to have different colored braces. Some other features of the plugin require a paid subscription. But for the colored braces you don't need a licence:

Other paid plugins (€2 per year) Color Brackets

when you click on the line itself, it lights up. But when you click on the bracket, only the bracket lights up. Is there a way that when select the bracket, that the line on the left would also light up so that i can easily follow down the code as i read it?
